# Can Windows 7 be installed on a Macbook with Leopard using BootCamp?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, osx-leopard

The Apple website says

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3920

> Summary
>
> Apple will support Microsoft
>   Windows 7 (Home Premium, Professional,
>   and Ultimate) with Boot Camp in Mac OS
>   X Snow Leopard before the end of the
>   year. This support will require a
>   software update to Boot Camp.

so what about Leopard?  This seems not so typical of Apple to say something that is quite incomplete... to mention about Snow Leopard and not Leopard -- many people still run Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work. [This blog post](http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/15/using-boot-camp-to-install-windows-7-on-your-mac-the-complete-walkthrough/) explains in detail how to go about installing.

Comment: hm, if there is something that is from Apple to confirm it, it'd be best.  (or if 2 or 3 places confirm it working).  thanks.

Comment: via Wiki - 
"Boot Camp is a utility included with Apple Inc.'s Mac OS X v10.5 "Leopard" and v10.6 "Snow Leopard" operating systems that assists users in installing Microsoft Windows XP, or Vista on Intel-based Macintosh computers. Apple does not yet support Windows 7 installations using Boot Camp (see Windows 7 section for details), many users have successfully installed Windows 7 using Boot Camp "
So no "word" from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for this functionality to be implemented why don't you use a Virtual Machine? I have a mac too and I find it to be much easier to run a Virtual Machine in OSX than deal with having to restart every time you want to switch operating systems. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is pretty good and free. [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) has more features but it also costs money. You could also use [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/). Honestly VirtualBox is good enough and has enough features. One thing that is for sure, they are all compatible with Windows 7. I have had no problems on both Leopard and Snow Leopard running Windows 7 in a Virtualized Environment.

To answer your question in the comment. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines) article there are other virtualization options for Mac OS. How good they are, and if they are free, you will have to look into yourself. If I was you I would just use VirtualBox. Just because it's free doesn't mean you shouldn't give it a chance.

Comment: VMWare Player is free... but is it only for PCs?  so the only free solution on the Mac is VirtualBox?